# Cardinality of open sets of $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $d \in \mathbb{N}$, then count the number of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

I just don't know how to start. I think I understand how I should count sets, but for this one, I really don't see it... How should I do this?

Comment: Do you know how many open sets there are in $\mathbb{R}$ (that is, $d=1$)?

Comment: No idea.. I don't see how to approach it.

Comment: Each open set is a countable union of open boxes $(a_1,b_1)\times...\times (a_d,b_d)$ with rationals $a_1,...,a_d,b_1,...,b_d$. Therefore, the open sets have an injection to the set of sequences of rational numbers.  The latter has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, the cardinality of the open sets is not larger than the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. Conversely, since for each real number $r$ the set $(r-1/2,r+1/2)^d$ is open, the inequality also holds in reverse.

Comment: Alright, do you know a [**base**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) for the topology on $\mathbb{R}$? If you do, do you know how many elements it has? This doesn't immediately solve the problem, of course - in general (and in this case) the topology as a whole has more open sets than just those in some base - but it's a good first step.

Comment: A base for the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ would be $(p, q)$ for $p$ and $q$ rational numbers, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @yixing why is each open set a countable union of such open boxes?

Comment: @Whatamidoing For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ divide the space by a grid (hyperplanes parallel to the axes) of size $1/n$. Pick the boxes of the grid that fall completely inside the open set. That is a sequence of of boxes and all points of the open set will fall inside one of those boxes for some very large $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $B$ is a countably infinite base (basis) for a topology $T$ then the cardinal $|T|$  (the cardinal of the set of all open sets) is at most $|\Bbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}=2^{|B|}$ because $T$ is the functional image of  P$(B)$ (the Power-set of $B$, the set  of all subsets of $B$)   via the function $f(A)=\cup A$ for all $A\subset B$.

For $n\in \Bbb N$ the set $B=\{ \prod_{i=1}^n(a_i,b_i): a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n\in \Bbb Q\}$ is a countable base for $\Bbb R^n.$

So the cardinal $|T_n|$ of the topology $T_n$ on $\Bbb R^n$ is at most $|\Bbb R|.$

And $|T_n|\geq |\Bbb R|$ because $T_n$ has a subset $\{(r,r+1)^n:r\in \Bbb R\}$ that has cardinal   $|\Bbb R|.$

By the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem (a.k.a. Cantor-Bernstein & Schroeder-Bernstein) and the Axiom of Choice, therefore $|T_n|=|\Bbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}.$